# Update immutable state with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using Redux to update my state which is immutable. I want to update nested array of object in my reducer by simply targeting list[] as I need to update it with new object. My first item's (board1) list does get updated as I dispatch action but once I dispatch for the next item(s) board2 and above, they overwrite my state and it return single item. Your help would be highly appreciated.. Thanks

```
const initialState = {
  board: [
    { boardId: 1, boardname: "board1", list: [] },
    { boardId: 2, boardname: "board2", list: [] }
  ]
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_LIST":
      state = {
        ...state.board,
        board: [
          ...state.board[action.payload.boardId - 1],
          {
            ...state.board[action.payload.boardId - 1],
            list: [
              ...state.board[action.payload.boardId - 1].list,
              {
                listId: state.board[action.payload.boardId - 1].list.length + 1,
                listname: action.payload.listname
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return state;
}
```

Comment: you've tagged the question with `immutable.js`, but seem to be using the ES6 spread operator rather than any of the great nested structure update functionality that `immutable.js` provides

Comment: I would recommend the icepick library instead.

Answer (score 0):

My choice is to use dotprop immutable.

https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable.

In addition. For updating different keys at once. I write a wrapper function to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You are using ES6 spread operator which isn't bad, but it starts to get annoying when working with nested objects. My advice is to try [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer), it will make your life much easier!!!